# Control background not displaying the way I want

Tags: c#, winforms, custom-controls, inkscape

Ok so I have a custom control and I am applying a background gradient to it. The control that it is in is set to anchor left and right and the image is set to Stretch on the control.

Here is what the background image looks like when its in the normal size of the form.

[image: Normal]

Here is what the background image looks like when the control is stretched.

[image: Distorted]

Obviously I want it to look like the top one as far as the edges go. I am using Inkscape to develop the background image. Any help on how to avoid this blurry edge would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest trying 9 images in your control, one for every edge and one for every corner plus the middle container, maybe you've seen this technique in a lot of websites. If you set all images with good anchor, the top and bottom edges will stretch only sideways and the right and left will stretch upward and downward. The corners would never change and the container would be completly stretchable. I am worried about flickering though since it is in a winform. Worth trying.

If you use a fixed image, even if it is bigger and you shrink it, you'll lose the corners proportions.

Comment: Just out of curiosity would I not have to worry about flickering if I was using a WPF control?

Answer (score 0):

When the system resizes the image it is approximating the missing pixels in the new stretched image. There is nothing you can do to prevent the blurring from occurring. The only sensible option I think is adding the image in higher resolution (which should be easy since you use Inkscape to create them) and have the system shrink it instead of stretch it.

Comment: I see, when I tried to export a high res image in Inkscape that worked successfully. However, when I set it to the background image of my control it is clearly not shrinking itself, unless I set the BackgroundImageLayout to stretch. Any suggestions?

Comment: What is the size of the control background and what is the size of the image exported from Inkscape?

Comment: I exported the background as extremely large thinking this would resolve my blurry issue. So I did something like 1380 x 166 and my control is 520 x 166 at normal width. When I maximize of course the width grows.

Comment: OK, with such big picture I would suggest going with Erik's approach by slicing the big image into separate images for every edge and every corner. You can't reliably stretch an image of such size. Eventually use a single-color background and draw the frame and the rounded corner programmatically.